# Redirect APEX domain to subdomain with Route53, CloudFront w/ Cache, ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

What I'm planning is to redirect `example.com` into `test.example.com`. (that should not be A record - the requirement was the change of the domain so the fact that it is in test domain is apparent.)

However, I found out that APEX domains cannot be CNAME record([link](https://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain)), so I thought redirection on CloudFront or beyond(nginx, expressjs) is appropriate, thereby I set two A records from `example.com` and `beta.example.com` to CF DNS name.

However with Cached CF I think there might be problem related to redirection.

For example, when a user tries to connect to `example.com` as a first hit(CF Cache miss), that request is passed into express and will be responded with 302 redirect to `test.example.com`.

However, when another user tries to connect to `test.example.com`, the request will be sent to CloudFront as request of `/`, so CF will return 302 redirect instead of passing it to express which makes no sence.

How can I solve this issue? Do I have to ditch caching for `/` resource or is there another way around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing `Behavior` > `Edit` > `Cache Based on Selected Request Headers` to `whitelist`, and then adding `Host` header to whitelist.